# facebook app request not show the notification in mobile app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have invite friends feature in my application fan page and I am using the following code to select friends for sending them application request.

```
       FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Invite friends',
     });
```

Here is the screenshot of popup window to select friends.

[image]

When I select user/s and click on "Send Requests" button, the application request  notification shows in the web browser for corresponding user/s face-book account, but not works in native mobile face-book app.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your app a native mobile app as well as a web app?